# how top-level async web requests handle the reponse

Tags: asynchronous, web, networking

I have fundumental question about how async requests work at top level.

Imagin if we have a top level route called `HomePage()`. This route is an **async** route and within this route we call to 10 different APIs before sending the response(image it takes like 5 seconds, remember this is an example to understand the concept and these numbers are for learning purposes). All of these api requests are **awaited**. So the request handler just releases the thread hanlding this request and goes to handle other requests until the response for these apis come back. So lets add this constraint. Our network card can handle only 1 connection and that one is held open till the response for the request to `HomePage` is ready. Therefor we cannot make any other requests to the server so whats the difference if this whole thing was sync from the beggining. We cannot drop the connection to the first request to `HomePage` because if that's the case then how are we ever going to send back the response for that request and we cannot handle new requests because the connection is kept open.
I suspect that my problem is how the reponse is sent back on top level async routes.
Can anybody give a deep dive explaination on how these requests are handled that can take more requests and still send back the response(because if it can send back a response the connection HAS TO HAVE KEPT ALIVE). Examples would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So lets add this constraint. Our network card can handle only 1 connection

That constraint cannot exist. Network cards handle packets, not connections. Connections are a virtual construct that exist in the host computer.

> Can anybody give a deep dive explaination on how these requests are handled that can take more requests and still send back the response(because if it can send back a response the connection HAS TO HAVE KEPT ALIVE).

Of course the connection is kept alive. The top-level `async` method will return the thread to the thread pool, where it is available to handle any other requests.

If you have some artificial constraint on your web app that prevents it from having more than one connection, then there won't be any other requests to handle, and the thread pool threads will do nothing.

Comment: hi, can you please leave a URL for me to read about it? what to search?? Because i've read that there is a limit which is defined by the hardware/software. Then what is the definition of ALIVE CONNECTION then. I might be very wrong in many aspects based on your answer. Thanks for your time and knowledge sharing Stephen >_<!!! please elaborate tnx

Comment: There's no explicit limit; it's whatever the hardware can handle. That's usually a few thousand or tens of thousands of connections per server.

Comment: wait but you just said there are no limits in connections and it is limitless on any hardware. I guess I'm not getting what you are saying correctly. "That constraint cannot exist. Network cards handle packets, not connections. Connections are a virtual construct that exist in the host computer"

Comment: There are no *explicit* limits. There are several implicit limits: network bandwidth, CPU cycles, and memory space are common examples.

Comment: so basically we keep the connection alive, BUT we release the thread handling it till the response is ready. This means the connection is open for longer (usually) but the number of requests that we can handle are much much more. Because the number of threads are much less that the number of requests that a network can handle right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The slowdown of the response time is usually immeasurably small.